# Intel Chipset Programming

Tags: c++, memory, controller, intel, chipset

Does anyone know how to get start with writing a program to access, say, an intel memory controller hub, such as the intel 5400 mch or the intel p45 mch?  Do I need Intel's Parallel Composer studio to get started?  Can I simply get started with C/C++ programming in Visual Studio C++? If so, how do I get started?

Comment: What do you mean "access the memory controller hub"? You do that every time you touch memory! What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I found some programmer's manuals on Intel's website.  This is just what I was looking for.

Comment: @user770402 can you post those links as an answer, as the fact you got 9 up-votes there seemed to be a lot of interest in it.

Comment: http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/

Comment: @user770402: I suggest adding it as an "answer", worded suitably. If it's a good answer, you'll get upvotes and an hour later you'll be able to accept it - which means you'll get even more rep, ultimately, and right now your rep is very low.

Comment: ...and your question won't appear as "unanswered" anymore :)

Answer (score 3):

I found the programmer's reference manuals on Intel's website.  This is all I was looking for
www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals